# Strange Date Format in RavenDB Index

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I'm having some trouble with date formats in indexes.  They're 
serializing to something indeserializable.  Our entities have this 
shape:

```
  [Serializable] 
  public class Publication 
  { 
    public Guid? Id { get; set; } 
    public PublicationRendering Rendering { get; protected internal set; } 
    public DateRange SuggestedActiveRange { get; protected set; } 
    public DateRange ActualActiveRange { get; protected internal set; } 
    ... 
  } 
  public class DateRange 
  { 
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; } 
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; } 
    ... 
  }
```

The document is serialized properly:

```
publications/806059ce-fd7a-4655-8e0e-9fff00f5ebd3 
{ 
  ... 
  "SuggestedActiveRange": { 
    "StartDate": "2011-11-22T00:00:00.0000000Z", 
    "EndDate": "2012-01-22T00:00:00.0000000Z", 
    "TimeSpan": "61.00:00:00" 
  }, 
  "ActualActiveRange": { 
    "StartDate": "2011-11-22T00:00:00.0000000Z", 
    "EndDate": "2012-01-22T00:00:00.0000000Z", 
    "TimeSpan": "61.00:00:00" 
  }, 
  ... 
}
```

And I'm defining my index as such (it's a multi-reduce):

```
  public class PublishedPolicyIndex : 
    AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<PublishedPolicyIndex.ReduceResult> 
  { 
    public PublishedPolicyIndex() { 
      AddMap<Publication>(publications => publications.Select(publication => new { 
        ArtifactId = "artifacts/" + publication.Rendering.ArtifactId, 
        ActiveStartDate = publication.ActualActiveRange.StartDate, 
        ActiveEndDate = publication.ActualActiveRange.EndDate, 
        ViewingPrincipals = (string[]) null, 
        ... 
      })); 
      AddMap<Artifact>(artifacts => artifacts.Select(artifact => new { 
        ArtifactId = artifact.Id, 
        ActiveStartDate = (string) null, 
        ActiveEndDate = (string) null, 
        artifact.ViewingPrincipals, 
        ... 
      })); 
      Reduce = results => results.GroupBy(result => result.ArtifactId).Select(g => new { 
        ArtifactId = g.Key, 
        ActiveStartDate = g.Select(x => x.ActiveStartDate).SingleOrDefault(x => x != null), 
        ActiveEndDate = g.Select(x => x.ActiveEndDate).SingleOrDefault(x => x != null), 
        ViewingPrincipals = g.Select(x => x.ViewingPrincipals).SingleOrDefault(x => x != null), 
        ... 
      }); 
      Analyzers = new Dictionary<Expression<Func<ReduceResult, object>>, string> { 
        {rr => rr.ActiveStartDate, "Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer"}, 
        {rr => rr.ActiveEndDate, "Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer"}, 
        ... 
      }; 
      Stores.Add(x => x.ActiveStartDate, FieldStorage.Yes); 
      Stores.Add(x => x.ActiveEndDate, FieldStorage.Yes); 
    } 
    public class ReduceResult : IReduceResults 
    { 
      public string ArtifactId { get; set; } 
      public string ActiveStartDate { get; set; } 
      public string ActiveEndDate { get; set; } 
      public string[] ViewingPrincipals { get; set; } 
      ... 
    } 
  }
```

But when I look in my index I have this data:

```
{ 
  "ArtifactId": "artifacts/533b8cba-8b8f-4c23-b89a-9fff00f5ebd3", 
  "ActiveStartDate": "20111122000000000", 
  "ActiveEndDate": "20120322000000000", 
  "ViewingPrincipals": [ 
    "b0202923-eb07-493d-a0b5-9fff00f5ebd3" 
  ], 
  ... 
}
```

It's almost as if it were hashing these dates.  Maybe I didn't setup 
my field store correctly?  If I explicitly call .ToString("u"), it 
will store the dates in a format that can be deserialized, but not 
quite equal to the format I want, plus that's too messy.

Comment: @amoss I would try posting your question to the RavenDB Google Group. Ayende and the other Raven folks monitor that user group.